# Cannot find -lxi

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to compile and run an OpenGL/GLUT program i created on another pc on my virtual machine ubuntu at home. I've installed freeglut3 and the other OpenGL libraries, but when I try to compile I get:
  cannot find -lXi

This is the line in my Makefile:

```
LDLIBS=-lGL -lGLEW -lglut -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lm
```

I cannot seem to find which library it is I still need to install?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you installed the corresponding -dev packages? Also, I think -lXi corresponds to libxi-dev.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need libXi-devel (or equivalent):

```
sudo apt-get install libxi-dev
```

libXi provides an X Window System client interface to the XINPUT extension to the X protocol.